# Prove that f'=f iff f is an exponential funtion

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-writing

Written more formally, prove that $f' = f \iff \exists c \in \mathbb{R} : f = c * \exp$

In other words, I guess, it's enough to prove that $\exp$ and $f(x) = 0$ are the only functions that are equal to its derivatives. How can I do that? I'll be grateful for a hint instead of a full proof.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Let $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{e^x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a hint, consider the function $h(x)=f(x)e^{-x}$ where $f(x)$ is a solution of the differential equation.

However, for the sake of completion, I shall write out the full proof. Do not read it if you do not wish, unless you get stuck.

$f(x)=ce^x$ then $f'(x)=ce^x$ since the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$ and $c$ is a constant. Thus $f'(x)=f(x)$

Thus, we can easily see that $f(x)=ce^x$ satisfies the differential equation, and thus we can safely say that a solution exists.

$h'(x)=f'(x)e^{-x}-f(x)e^{-x}=(f'(x)-f(x))e^{-x}=0$ since $f(x)=f'(x)$ is the same as $f'(x)-f(x)=0$

Thus, $h(x)=c$ where $c$  is an arbitrary constant.

Therefore, $f(x)=ce^x$.

QED.

Comment: Let me edit my answer.

Comment: For the sake of completion, I think you also have to prove the other (quite trivial) implication since it's an iff :) thanks for the hint!

Comment: I thought by your question "I guess, it's enough to prove that" meant that you already did that part. I'll write it though.

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple differential equation and taking a derivative:

Proof:

First, suppose $f(x) = y$ and $\frac{dy}{dx} = y$. Then $dy = y \hspace{1mm} dx \Rightarrow \frac{1}{y} dy = dx \Rightarrow ln(y) = x + C_{1} \Rightarrow y = Ce^{x} $

Thus, we see that if $f'(x) = f(x)$, then $f = Ce^{x}$.

Conversely, if $f(x) = y = Ce^{x}$, then we have that $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}Ce^{x} = C \frac{d}{dx} e^{x} = Ce^{x}$

Thus, we see that if $f(x) = Ce^{x}$, then $f' = f$.

This completes the proof.